# Force X application to run in a Window

Tags: linux, xorg, window, fullscreen

I'm running X server 1.20.3, with i3 as a window manager.

Some steam game are trying to run in full screen. I want them to run in a window.

Is there a way to make X not honor their request to go to fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** this answer is partially based on [another one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24062) from [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Check out **[`Xephyr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr)**. It will start a **X server** which will output for a **given display** all requests in a **dedicated window**.

[Example](http://linux-attitude.fr/post/x-dans-x) (taken from [Linux-Attitude.fr](http://linux-attitude.fr), a site in french):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# add -ac to disables access control to make it easy (cf. man Xserver)
# :1 is the display id
Xephyr -ac :1 & 
# launch the application with the display :1
DISPLAY=:1 xclock & # launch the application
```

You can adjust the window size of Xephyr using `-screen widthxheight`. See man page for more informations.

Comment: @qdil, Does this answer suit your question? If so, please mark it as accepted.